# Number of n-words such that a and b are not neighbors.

Tags: combinatorics

> Question:How many n-words from the alphabet {a,b,c,d} are such that a and b are never neighbors?

1.There are $4^n$ ways to arrange the four letters.

2.There are $(n-1)$$2^{n-1}$ ways of arranging a and b together.(is it so?)

3.Hence,the required number is $4^n$-$(n-1)$$2^{n-1}$.

Have I counted the right number of things?

**I am looking for a very beautiful Combinatoric proof.**

> Edit:I realized I had incorrectly assumed that a and b occurred only once in the sequence.

Comment: Can you explain the logic for $2$? it is wrong

Comment: Since you fix a and b,you have 2 choices for $n-2$ numbers

Comment: oh, that is wrong because what you have to count is the number of sequences in which there is at least one appearance of consecutive a and b's.

Comment: oops...I didn't get you.Would you mind posting the solution?

Comment: If I manage to solve it gladly :)

Comment: @Gamamal It looks like I assumed that $a$ and $b$ occur only once in the n-word.Maybe a little summation will help!

Comment: Presumably subwords aa and bb are allowed, but ab and ba are not.  Is that correct?

Comment: That sounds right

Answer (score 2):

I found something with recursion, I don't know if it helps.

Let $s_n$ be the number of $n$-words ending in $a$ (equal to the number of $n$-words ending in $b$) and let $t_n$ be the number of $n$-words ending in $c$ (equal to the number of $n$-words ending in $d$).

Then we have:

$s_{n+1}=s_n+2t_n$ since an $n+1$ word ending in $a$ is obtained by taking a $n$ word ending in $a,c$ or $d$ and adding an $a$ at the end.

$t_{n+1}=2s_n+2t_{n}$ since an $n+1$ $n$-word ending in $c$ is obtained by taking any $n$-word (ending in any of $a,b,c,d$ and adding a $c$ at the end.

Let $f_n$ be then number of $n$-words. Then $f_n=t_{n+1}$ since an $n+1$-word ending in $c$ can be obtained by taking an $n$ word and just attaching a $c$ at the end.

We have the recursion $f_{n+1}=3s_n+3s_n+4t_n+4t_n$ since a $n$-word ending in $a$ can be extended in three ways to an $n+1$-word (likewise for wn $n$-word ending in $b$. On the other hand words ending in $b$ can ended in $4$ ways.

So $f_{n+1}=6s_n+8t_n$, using $s_n+s_n+t_n+t_n=f_n$ we get $f_{n+1}=3f_n+2t_n=3f_n+2f_{n-1}$

So $f_{n+1}=3f_n+2f_{n-1}$.

We could obtain an exponential formula similar to that of the fibonaccis, but I have a gut feeling it will have an irrational coefficient just like the formula for the fibonaccis.

Lets use the recursion to compute some values.

By inspection we have:

$f_1=4,f_2=16-2=14$.

From here:

$f_3=50,f_4=178,f_5=634,f_6=2258,f_7=8042,f_8=28642,f_9=102010,f_{10}=363314$

Comment: This is indeed correct and elegant.But,I want to see a non-recurrence relation proof :)

Comment: @AsG:  If so, you should say so in your question and not accept this answer yet.  You should upvote it, but the accept may tell others that your problem is solved.  There may be an neat combinatorial way to get the answer (though I doubt it-the fact that you can have multiple ab's makes i hard)

Comment: I don't think a non-recurrence relation closed formula will be possible. This sequence is very similar to the Fibonacci sequence. The Fibonacci sequence has a closed form formula, it can be obtained by taking the recursion, finding the generating and reading of the terms. However the formula for the fibnacci sequence is almost never used since it requires approximating an irrational number first.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula in step 2 is wrong.

For a counterexample, let's begin to count the number of $3$-words that have $a$ and $b$ as neighbors. Your formula says there should be $(3-1)2^{3-1}=8$ of them. But look at these:

```
aba
abb
abc
abd

baa
bab
bac
bad

aab
cab
dab

bba
cba
dba
```

These are more than $8$! (The two groups have the first occurrence of $ab$ or $ba$ as the first two letters, and the next two groups have the first occurrence as the last two letters.)

Comment: I had assumed that a and b can occur only once in the sequence :)

Comment: @AsG: That assumption should be explicitly stated in the problem, if that is the case.

Comment: That is indeed not the case as I realized later.

Answer (score 0):

If an $n-1$ word ends in $c$ or $d$, you can extend it to an $n$ word in $4$ ways.  If it ends in $a$ or $b$, you can extend it in three ways, presuming that $aa$ and $bb$ are allowed.  Define $A(n)$ as the number of acceptable $n$ words that end in $a$ or $b$ and $B(n)$ as the number of  acceptable $n$ words that end in $c$ or $d$.  We have
$A(1)=B(1)=2, A(n)=A(n-1)+2B(n-1), B(n)=2A(n-1)+2B(n-1)$
and your answer is $A(n)+B(n)$

I made an Excel sheet, found $4, 14, 50, 178, 634, 2258, 8042, 28642, 102010, 363314, 1293962, 4608514, 16413466, 58457426$, looked it up in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A055099), and found the generating function $\frac {1+x}{1-3x-2x^2}$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ can each only appear once, the number of unrestricted strings is much smaller than $4^n$.  It is $n(n-1)2^{n-2}+2n2^{n-1}+2^n=(n^2+3n+4)2^{n-2}$ In the first term, which includes both $a$ and $b$ we first pick where the $a$ goes, then where the $b$ goes.  Of these, only $2(n-1)2^(n-2)$ will have the $a$ and $b$ together

Comment: And if $a$ and $b$ occurred twice,it would be $2^2$*$(n-3)$*2^$n-4$,right?

Comment: I did try for more $a$'s and $b$'s,but it already looks complicated(I haven't yet succeeded in finding the general formula).I shall stick with the solution provided by Gamamal for now :)

Comment: If a and b occur exactly twice each, you have ${n \choose 4}{4 \choose 2}2^{n-4}$ where first you pick the positions for a's and b's, then you pick the a's, then you pick c's and d's for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

By establishing a system of recurrence relations one quickly finds a recurrence relation that can solve this. I will generalise the problem by assuming that the alphabet has $k$ letters without restriction and $l$ letters that cannot be adjacent among each other, except when the letters are identical; the problem in the question is a special case for $k=l=2$.

Let $t_n$ be the number of such words not ending with a restricted letter, and $s_n$ the number of such words ending with a letter among the $l$ restricted ones (I follow the nomenclature used in another answer); we shall ultimately be interested in $t_n+s_n$. The initial values are $t_0=1$, $s_0=0$ (the negative formulation for $t_n$ was to get these cases right). We have for $n>0$ that $t_n=(t_{n-1}+s_{n-1})k$ (one can place an unrestricted letter after and valid word of length $n-1$) and $s_n=t_{n-1}l+s_{n-1}$ (one can either extend a word not ending with a restricted letter by any restricted letter, or extend a word ending with a restricted letter by repeating the final letter). In matrix form one has
$$
  v_n = A\, v_{n-1}\qquad\hbox{where }v_n=\pmatrix{t_n\\s_n}\hbox{ and }A=\pmatrix{k&k\\l&1}
$$
Since the matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2-(k-1)A-k(l-1)I=0$ (since $X^2-(k-1)X+k(1-l)$ is its characteristic polynomial) the vector sequence satisfies the recurrence $v_{n+2}-(k+1)v_{n+1}-k(l-1)v_n=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. The same linear recurrence holds for the numeric sequence $(t_n+s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ that interests us.

We can find a formula for the generating series $S=\sum_{i\in\Bbb N}(t_n+s_n)X^n\in \Bbb Z[[X]]$. The recurrence relation ensures that the product series $S\bigl(1-(k+1)X-k(l-1)X^2\bigr)$ has no nonzero terms of degree${}\geq2$, and from the initial values $t_0+s_0=1$ and $t_1+s_1=k+l$ one concludes that this product equals $1+(l-1)X$. In conclusion
$$
  \sum_{i\in\Bbb N}(t_n+s_n)X^n = \frac{1+(l-1)X}{1-(k+1)X-k(l-1)X^2}
$$
is the generating series for the number of solutions. In particular for $k=l=2$ one finds (without computer aid) the generating series $\frac{1+X}{1-3X-2X^2}$ that Ross Millikan also found.