# How many $n$-words from the alphabet $A=${$a,b,c,d$} are there such that $a$ and $b$ are never neighbors.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

How many $n$-words from the alphabet $A=${$a,b,c,d$} are there such that $a$ and $b$ are never neighbors.  $\\$
Source : Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel$\\$
The solution given in the book is related to, forming Recurrence relations. The problem is, I am a bit unfamiliar and to Recurrences so is it possible to solve this problem without using Recurrences ?$\\$
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: i want a solution which does not use recursions @JitendraSingh

Comment: metacheating (i.e. playing poker with the author), my **blind guess**, which could easily be wrong, is that a non-recursion approach will get ugly, *fast*.  *Usually*, when an author hand-picks a problem to demonstrate recursion, they are trying to motivate the student as to the **power** of recursion.  The best way to influence the student is with a problem that has no alternative elegant approach.  Beyond this blind speculation, my (prejudiced) attempt at an independent instinct, which could also easily be wrong, also suggests no elegant non-recursive method.

Comment: Note that in a word with $n$ characters, the number of $a$'s and $b$'s are each *variable*.

Comment: The other way I can think of would involve generating functions - and based on the question, I'm guessing that would be even more "beyond" the OP's current level of understanding.  (That would essentially be based on the language being expressible in terms of an unambiguous regular expression as $((aa^*|bb^*|\varepsilon)(c|d))^*(aa^*|bb^*|\varepsilon)$, and then going through the terms from bottom up to construct each subterm's generating function.)

Comment: If my calculations are right, the eventual answer is some linear combination of $\left( \frac{3\pm\sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n$ which just screams that either some recurrence relation or generating function approach will probably be necessary.

Comment: This question is already present at least twice on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1721000/18880 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330286/18880